# Evaluating $\int^1_0 \frac2{\sqrt{2-x^2}} dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\int^1_0 \frac2{\sqrt{2-x^2}} dx$$
using substitution $x=\sqrt 2 \sin \theta$
$$\int^{\pi/4}_0 \frac{2\cos \theta d\theta}{\sqrt{2-2\sin^2 \theta}} = \int^{\pi/4}_0 \frac{2\cos\theta d\theta}{\sqrt2 \cos\theta} = \int^{\pi/4}_0 \frac{2d\theta}{\sqrt2}  = \int^{\pi/4}_0 \frac{2\cdot\sqrt2 d\theta}{\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2} = \int^{\pi/4}_0 \sqrt2d\theta = \sqrt2 \theta = \sqrt2 (\frac\pi4 - 0) = \sqrt2 \frac\pi4 $$

The problem is that the answer is $\frac\pi2$. Where did I make a mistake?

UPDATE:

using substitution $x=\sqrt 2 \sin\theta \rightarrow dx=\sqrt2\cos\theta$
$$\int^{\pi/4}_0 \frac{2\sqrt2\cos\theta}{\sqrt{2-2\sin^2\theta}} = \int^{\pi/4}_0 \frac{2\sqrt2\cos\theta}{\sqrt2 cos\theta} = \int^{\pi/4}_0 \frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt2}  = \int^{\pi/4}_0 2 = 2 \theta = 2 (\frac\pi4 - 0) = \frac\pi2 $$

Comment: $\sin\;$? $\;\cos\;$ ? You may want to add argument to functions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Putting $x=\sqrt2\sin\theta, dx=\sqrt2\cos\theta d\theta$ (you missed this $\sqrt2$)

$$\int^1_0 \frac2{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx=2\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\frac{\sqrt2\cos\theta d\theta}{\sqrt2\cos\theta}=2\int_0^{\frac\pi4}d\theta$$

Comment: Yes, now I see. Thank you. Should I edit my post or leave it?

Comment: @Max, my pleasure. It's you call whether to edit the question or leave as is

Answer (score 1):

you should substitute $dx$ by $\sqrt{2}\cos t dt$

Answer (score 0):

An approach:

$$\int\limits_0^1\frac2{\sqrt{2-x^2}}dx=\frac2{\sqrt2}\int\limits_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x{\sqrt2}\right)^2}}=2\int\limits_0^1\frac{\left(\frac x{\sqrt2}\right)'dx}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac x{\sqrt2}\right)^2}}=$$

$$=\left.2\arcsin\frac x{\sqrt2}\right|_0^1=2\arcsin\frac1{\sqrt2}=2\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)=\frac\pi2$$

Comment: Interesting way. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Graphth. I don't care so much about some downvotes. I think I have a stalker since several of my answers were downvoted lately. Oh well.